# Clearing Woocommerce cart on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce, cart

So, found this snippet that clears the basket and it works well when added to functions.php:

```
function my_empty_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
add_action('init', 'my_empty_cart');
```

How can I modify this and make it empty the cart only when certain pages are loaded? I played around with `if ( is_page( 'pageID' )` but couldn't get it working properly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
global $post;
if($post->ID == 'something'){
add_action('init', 'my_empty_cart');
}


function my_empty_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
```

for more [readings](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-current-page-id-not-post-id).

check this [link](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/package-WooCommerce.Functions.html) it have all the page / function codes in woocommerce

Hope its works..

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately didn't work. Tried `if ( is_page('order-received') ) {` as well, but still nothing. Weird:/

Comment: is the post Id getting any value ? this may help http://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-woocommerce-page-urls/

Comment: Ok, tried the `woocommerce_get_page_id( ‘thanks’ );` but still not emptying the cart. Here's the whole snippet:
`global $post;
if(is_page( woocommerce_get_page_id('thanks'))) {
add_action('init', 'my_empty_cart');
}


function my_empty_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
`
Many thanks!:))

Answer (score 0):

WordPress conditional didnt worked for me either so i did something that dont relies on WordPress conditionals:

```
/*empty cart if user come to homepage*/
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') { 
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
 }
}
```

if u want to add to certain pages u can edit the conditional exp: (didnt try it)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === get_permalink('post_id'))
```

if the `get_permalink` doest work use the exact url exp: `'https://www.domain.name/post-75'`